# Firefox plugin to capture signature (via stylus/tablet)

Tags: image, firefox, handwriting, electronic-signature

I am wondering if anyone has any experience capturing signatures with a tablet/stylus over the internet.
How would you write a plug-in that uses an ActiveX control and can securely post the signature over the web?

Or maybe you've got a better idea how to handle this...

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] To be more specific, I need something that can hook up to a signature pad like you would use at Best Buy to make a legal signature.

Answer (score 1):

I would somehow use flash that would draw to a bitmap, then encode them as an image then upload them to your server.

After a few minutes of googling, i found this.

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/drawingboard.htm

**Edit**
http://www.topazsystems.com/ has an activex control

Answer (score 0):

You can embed DocuSign and render it on any device (tablet, phone, etc).  DocuSign detects if it's on a mobile device and allow people to draw a signature.  By using a system like DocuSign you get the added validity and acceptance by legal and financial institutions.